# Spring boot 1.5.x jetty server gzip not working Request method not GET

Tags: spring-boot, jetty, gzip, embedded-jetty

Spring boot 1.5.x and jetty server gzip not working post,put only work get

server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.min-response-size=0
server.compression.mime-types=application/json,application/xml,text/html,text/xml,text/plain

Answer (score 0):

Because of org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHanlder work only GET method. 
You can override gzipHandler
Spring boot GzipHandler created code:

```
private static class Jetty93GzipHandlerFactory implements GzipHandlerFactory {

    @Override
    public HandlerWrapper createGzipHandler(Compression compression) {
        GzipHandler handler = new GzipHandler();
        handler.setMinGzipSize(compression.getMinResponseSize());
        handler.setIncludedMimeTypes(compression.getMimeTypes());
        if (compression.getExcludedUserAgents() != null) {
            handler.setExcludedAgentPatterns(compression.getExcludedUserAgents());
        }
        return handler;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can not override GzipHandler. upgrade spring boot version